# My page views from my application insights of an ASP.NET Core app are not showing

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I've created a simple ASP.NET app, with the basic template, nothing changed. And I added a connected service for Azure Application Insights for my app. It's all good and it shows in my Azure Portal account, the live metrics are showing some things:[image]

The problem is, I cannot access my page views, not in portal and not in visual studio:
[image]

[image]

So what could be the problem, what I missed or what I forgot to add? Also. I don't have an applicationinsights.config file.

Comment: Please share your `appsettings.json` and `Program.cs` file.

Comment: I have post my solution, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have an applicationinsights.config file.

Earlier after adding `Application Insights` from `Connected Services`, `applicationinsights.config` used to get created automatically in the root directory of the Application.

But now - a -days, we don't see it.

- We can create the `applicationinsights.config` manually.

We can Track `Page Views` in 2 ways.

***Way 1:***

I have taken the refences from the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-overview#send-telemetry-from-your-app).

Add the below script in the `.cshtml` files, where you want to track the views.

```cs
<script type="text/javascript">
    !function (T, l, y) { var S = T.location, k = "script", D = "instrumentationKey", C = "ingestionendpoint", I = "disableExceptionTracking", E = "ai.device.", b = "toLowerCase", w = "crossOrigin", N = "POST", e = "appInsightsSDK", t = y.name || "appInsights"; (y.name || T[e]) && (T[e] = t); var n = T[t] || function (d) { var g = !1, f = !1, m = { initialize: !0, queue: [], sv: "5", version: 2, config: d }; function v(e, t) { var n = {}, a = "Browser"; return n[E + "id"] = a[b](), n[E + "type"] = a, n["ai.operation.name"] = S && S.pathname || "_unknown_", n["ai.internal.sdkVersion"] = "javascript:snippet_" + (m.sv || m.version), { time: function () { var e = new Date; function t(e) { var t = "" + e; return 1 === t.length && (t = "0" + t), t } return e.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + t(1 + e.getUTCMonth()) + "-" + t(e.getUTCDate()) + "T" + t(e.getUTCHours()) + ":" + t(e.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + t(e.getUTCSeconds()) + "." + ((e.getUTCMilliseconds() / 1e3).toFixed(3) + "").slice(2, 5) + "Z" }(), iKey: e, name: "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights." + e.replace(/-/g, "") + "." + t, sampleRate: 100, tags: n, data: { baseData: { ver: 2 } } } } var h = d.url || y.src; if (h) { function a(e) { var t, n, a, i, r, o, s, c, u, p, l; g = !0, m.queue = [], f || (f = !0, t = h, s = function () { var e = {}, t = d.connectionString; if (t) for (var n = t.split(";"), a = 0; a < n.length; a++) { var i = n[a].split("="); 2 === i.length && (e[i[0][b]()] = i[1]) } if (!e[C]) { var r = e.endpointsuffix, o = r ? e.location : null; e[C] = "https://" + (o ? o + "." : "") + "dc." + (r || "services.visualstudio.com") } return e }(), c = s[D] || d[D] || "", u = s[C], p = u ? u + "/v2/track" : d.endpointUrl, (l = []).push((n = "SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details)", a = t, i = p, (o = (r = v(c, "Exception")).data).baseType = "ExceptionData", o.baseData.exceptions = [{ typeName: "SDKLoadFailed", message: n.replace(/\./g, "-"), hasFullStack: !1, stack: n + "\nSnippet failed to load [" + a + "] -- Telemetry is disabled\nHelp Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2128109\nHost: " + (S && S.pathname || "_unknown_") + "\nEndpoint: " + i, parsedStack: [] }], r)), l.push(function (e, t, n, a) { var i = v(c, "Message"), r = i.data; r.baseType = "MessageData"; var o = r.baseData; return o.message = 'AI (Internal): 99 message:"' + ("SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details) (" + n + ")").replace(/\"/g, "") + '"', o.properties = { endpoint: a }, i }(0, 0, t, p)), function (e, t) { if (JSON) { var n = T.fetch; if (n && !y.useXhr) n(t, { method: N, body: JSON.stringify(e), mode: "cors" }); else if (XMLHttpRequest) { var a = new XMLHttpRequest; a.open(N, t), a.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"), a.send(JSON.stringify(e)) } } }(l, p)) } function i(e, t) { f || setTimeout(function () { !t && m.core || a() }, 500) } var e = function () { var n = l.createElement(k); n.src = h; var e = y[w]; return !e && "" !== e || "undefined" == n[w] || (n[w] = e), n.onload = i, n.onerror = a, n.onreadystatechange = function (e, t) { "loaded" !== n.readyState && "complete" !== n.readyState || i(0, t) }, n }(); y.ld < 0 ? l.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e) : setTimeout(function () { l.getElementsByTagName(k)[0].parentNode.appendChild(e) }, y.ld || 0) } try { m.cookie = l.cookie } catch (p) { } function t(e) { for (; e.length;)!function (t) { m[t] = function () { var e = arguments; g || m.queue.push(function () { m[t].apply(m, e) }) } }(e.pop()) } var n = "track", r = "TrackPage", o = "TrackEvent"; t([n + "Event", n + "PageView", n + "Exception", n + "Trace", n + "DependencyData", n + "Metric", n + "PageViewPerformance", "start" + r, "stop" + r, "start" + o, "stop" + o, "addTelemetryInitializer", "setAuthenticatedUserContext", "clearAuthenticatedUserContext", "flush"]), m.SeverityLevel = { Verbose: 0, Information: 1, Warning: 2, Error: 3, Critical: 4 }; var s = (d.extensionConfig || {}).ApplicationInsightsAnalytics || {}; if (!0 !== d[I] && !0 !== s[I]) { var c = "onerror"; t(["_" + c]); var u = T[c]; T[c] = function (e, t, n, a, i) { var r = u && u(e, t, n, a, i); return !0 !== r && m["_" + c]({ message: e, url: t, lineNumber: n, columnNumber: a, error: i }), r }, d.autoExceptionInstrumented = !0 } return m }(y.cfg); function a() { y.onInit && y.onInit(n) } (T[t] = n).queue && 0 === n.queue.length ? (n.queue.push(a), n.trackPageView({})) : a() }(window, document, {
        src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js",        
        crossOrigin: "anonymous",       
        cfg: { 
            instrumentationKey: "********"
        }
    });
</script>
```

***OutPut:***

[image]

[image]

***Way 2:***

- As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#add-application-insights-manually), add the `applicationinsights.config` manually.

In `applicationinsights.config`,

- Add the   `IncludeType` for `PageView`.

```cs
<IncludeTypes>PageView</IncludeTypes>
```

- Add `Application Insight ConnectionString`.

```cs
  <ConnectionString>InstrumentationKey=******;IngestionEndpoint=https://westus2-2.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westus2.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/</ConnectionString>
```

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");  
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

***My `appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=****;IngestionEndpoint=https://westus2-2.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westus2.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}
```

Comment: I made those changes, I hope I did them right, but I still don't see the page views, here is my full project if that would be more helpful https://github.com/elenaisabella02/appinsight

Answer (score 0):

You can check the official doc, and I add below code and it works for me.

Follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-monitor/app-insights/asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data#no-data-on-page-views-browsers-and-usage) to troubleshoot,and [add below code in page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript-sdk#add-the-code-snippet). You should use `connectionString`, instead of `instrumentationKey`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
!function(T,l,y){var S=T.location,k="script",D="instrumentationKey",C="ingestionendpoint",I="disableExceptionTracking",E="ai.device.",b="toLowerCase",w="crossOrigin",N="POST",e="appInsightsSDK",t=y.name||"appInsights";(y.name||T[e])&&(T[e]=t);var n=T[t]||function(d){var g=!1,f=!1,m={initialize:!0,queue:[],sv:"5",version:2,config:d};function v(e,t){var n={},a="Browser";return n[E+"id"]=a[b](),n[E+"type"]=a,n["ai.operation.name"]=S&&S.pathname||"_unknown_",n["ai.internal.sdkVersion"]="javascript:snippet_"+(m.sv||m.version),{time:function(){var e=new Date;function t(e){var t=""+e;return 1===t.length&&(t="0"+t),t}return e.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+t(1+e.getUTCMonth())+"-"+t(e.getUTCDate())+"T"+t(e.getUTCHours())+":"+t(e.getUTCMinutes())+":"+t(e.getUTCSeconds())+"."+((e.getUTCMilliseconds()/1e3).toFixed(3)+"").slice(2,5)+"Z"}(),iKey:e,name:"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights."+e.replace(/-/g,"")+"."+t,sampleRate:100,tags:n,data:{baseData:{ver:2}}}}var h=d.url||y.src;if(h){function a(e){var t,n,a,i,r,o,s,c,u,p,l;g=!0,m.queue=[],f||(f=!0,t=h,s=function(){var e={},t=d.connectionString;if(t)for(var n=t.split(";"),a=0;a<n.length;a++){var i=n[a].split("=");2===i.length&&(e[i[0][b]()]=i[1])}if(!e[C]){var r=e.endpointsuffix,o=r?e.location:null;e[C]="https://"+(o?o+".":"")+"dc."+(r||"services.visualstudio.com")}return e}(),c=s[D]||d[D]||"",u=s[C],p=u?u+"/v2/track":d.endpointUrl,(l=[]).push((n="SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details)",a=t,i=p,(o=(r=v(c,"Exception")).data).baseType="ExceptionData",o.baseData.exceptions=[{typeName:"SDKLoadFailed",message:n.replace(/\./g,"-"),hasFullStack:!1,stack:n+"\nSnippet failed to load ["+a+"] -- Telemetry is disabled\nHelp Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2128109\nHost: "+(S&&S.pathname||"_unknown_")+"\nEndpoint: "+i,parsedStack:[]}],r)),l.push(function(e,t,n,a){var i=v(c,"Message"),r=i.data;r.baseType="MessageData";var o=r.baseData;return o.message='AI (Internal): 99 message:"'+("SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details) ("+n+")").replace(/\"/g,"")+'"',o.properties={endpoint:a},i}(0,0,t,p)),function(e,t){if(JSON){var n=T.fetch;if(n&&!y.useXhr)n(t,{method:N,body:JSON.stringify(e),mode:"cors"});else if(XMLHttpRequest){var a=new XMLHttpRequest;a.open(N,t),a.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json"),a.send(JSON.stringify(e))}}}(l,p))}function i(e,t){f||setTimeout(function(){!t&&m.core||a()},500)}var e=function(){var n=l.createElement(k);n.src=h;var e=y[w];return!e&&""!==e||"undefined"==n[w]||(n[w]=e),n.onload=i,n.onerror=a,n.onreadystatechange=function(e,t){"loaded"!==n.readyState&&"complete"!==n.readyState||i(0,t)},n}();y.ld<0?l.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e):setTimeout(function(){l.getElementsByTagName(k)[0].parentNode.appendChild(e)},y.ld||0)}try{m.cookie=l.cookie}catch(p){}function t(e){for(;e.length;)!function(t){m[t]=function(){var e=arguments;g||m.queue.push(function(){m[t].apply(m,e)})}}(e.pop())}var n="track",r="TrackPage",o="TrackEvent";t([n+"Event",n+"PageView",n+"Exception",n+"Trace",n+"DependencyData",n+"Metric",n+"PageViewPerformance","start"+r,"stop"+r,"start"+o,"stop"+o,"addTelemetryInitializer","setAuthenticatedUserContext","clearAuthenticatedUserContext","flush"]),m.SeverityLevel={Verbose:0,Information:1,Warning:2,Error:3,Critical:4};var s=(d.extensionConfig||{}).ApplicationInsightsAnalytics||{};if(!0!==d[I]&&!0!==s[I]){var c="onerror";t(["_"+c]);var u=T[c];T[c]=function(e,t,n,a,i){var r=u&&u(e,t,n,a,i);return!0!==r&&m["_"+c]({message:e,url:t,lineNumber:n,columnNumber:a,error:i}),r},d.autoExceptionInstrumented=!0}return m}(y.cfg);function a(){y.onInit&&y.onInit(n)}(T[t]=n).queue&&0===n.queue.length?(n.queue.push(a),n.trackPageView({})):a()}(window,document,{
src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js", // The SDK URL Source
// name: "appInsights", // Global SDK Instance name defaults to "appInsights" when not supplied
// ld: 0, // Defines the load delay (in ms) before attempting to load the sdk. -1 = block page load and add to head. (default) = 0ms load after timeout,
// useXhr: 1, // Use XHR instead of fetch to report failures (if available),
crossOrigin: "anonymous", // When supplied this will add the provided value as the cross origin attribute on the script tag
// onInit: null, // Once the application insights instance has loaded and initialized this callback function will be called with 1 argument -- the sdk instance (DO NOT ADD anything to the sdk.queue -- As they won't get called)
cfg: { // Application Insights Configuration
    connectionString: "CONNECTION_STRING"
}});
</script>
```

#### Test Result

*In azure portal metrics*

[image]

***Tips***

Don't forget to click here to change the data resource.

[image]

*In VS2022*

[image]

Comment: I made those changes in my code, but my page views are still not showing. Also, I made sure that I'm on the right resource like you mentioned earlier.

Comment: @ElenaIsabella Could you share more details, it works in my side, and I am willing help you check it.